# Image Not Loading In Fragment Using : Picasso/Glide

Tags: firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, android-glide

I have tried both glide and Picasso but I am not able to load image but other data like string getting fetched and displayed same image URL also able to store in string but not loading in image View, I need to know where I made mistake because of that image not able to display.

```
public class OwnerView extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NewPostAdapter,OwnerView.OwnerViewHolder> {
    
        //Context context;
        DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    
    
        public OwnerView(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NewPostAdapter> options) {
            super(options);
            //databaseReference = getRef(options).child("").getRef();
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OwnerView.OwnerViewHolder ownerViewHolder, int i, @NonNull NewPostAdapter newPostAdapter) {
    
            final String urrrl = newPostAdapter.getImg_url1();
            Log.d("Image Url Finding : ",urrrl);
            ownerViewHolder.own_add.setText(newPostAdapter.getArea_Owner());
            ownerViewHolder.own_mob.setText(newPostAdapter.getNumber_Owner());
            ownerViewHolder.own_type.setText(newPostAdapter.getType_Owner());
            //Glide.with(context).load(newPostAdapter.getImg_url1()).into(ownerViewHolder.imageView);
            Picasso.get().load(urrrl).into(ownerViewHolder.imageView);
    
            //Glide.with(ownerViewHolder.imageView.getContext()).load(urrrl).into(ownerViewHolder.imageView);
    
    
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public OwnerView.OwnerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
    
            return new OwnerViewHolder(view);
        }
    
        public static class OwnerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            TextView own_add,own_mob,own_type;
            ImageView imageView;
    
            public OwnerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                own_add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_owner);
                own_mob = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_owner);
                own_type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type_owner);
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    
    
            }
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes sir

Comment: What is the value of urrrl?

Comment: @AlexMamo it's URL of image from firebase

Comment: Maybe it's a UI-related issue. Have tried to set an image without the use of any library?

Comment: @AlexMamo No Problem When We Set Image Without using library means by using source image...